# Powershell: How to iterate and set Sound Playback and Sound Input device?

Tags: powershell

Well, one of the things that is worse in Win11 is that it is now several clicks to change audio playback device (where in Win10 it was two or three clicks).

Time to script it.

What is the method in powershell to:

- List audio output and input devices
- Set/change the audio output and input devices

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure if its gonna work on Windows 11 but its worth a try.

There is a module in powershell that can be used to manage sound devices and volume level. Try AudioDeviceCmdlets module from the PSGallery https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/AudioDeviceCmdlets/3.0.0.4

Then you can use `Get-AudioDevice -List` to see the available audio devices, and `Set-AudioDevice <AudioDevice> -index 1` to set the desired "AudioDevice" to be the default input/output.

More on the module here - https://github.com/frgnca/AudioDeviceCmdlets

Comment: Thanks! Totally works on Win11. This is the perfect module for this need.

Comment: This is great. Now I can write scripts to select each device and bind them to macro keys.